# Expected Type and Main

Tags: haskell

Total Haskell noob here. I have a simple function, and a main. I don't have any idea what this  error means:

```
Couldn't match expected type `IO t0' with actual type `Bool'
In the expression: main
When checking the type of the function `main'
```

when compiling the code:

```
is_instructor :: String -> Bool
is_instructor "Jeremy Erickson" = True
is_instructor x = False

main :: Bool
main = is_instructor "foo"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`main` is the thing that gets called when you run your programme. It is expected that a programme does in some way interact with the outside world (read input, print output, such things), therefore it's reasonable that a `main` should have the type `IO something`. For reasons of type safety and simplicity, that is a requirement in Haskell, like `main` in Java must have type `public static void main(String[] arrgh)`.

You probably wanted you value to be printed, so

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = print $ is_instructor "foo"
```

would be what you want.

Comment: Great, that works. Thank you. So if I wanted to put a signature on the main method, would it be "main :: IO Bool" still?

Comment: No, since you're printing, it would be `Main :: IO ()`. Printing doesn't yield anything interesting, so `print :: Show a => a -> IO ()`.

Comment: Sorry, still confused. When I use the Main :: IO () signature, I get "Invalid type signature: Main :: IO (). Should be of form <variable> :: <type>". Also, should I be defining an accompanying print binding if I use print :: Show a => a -> IO ()?

Comment: `main` must start with a lower case letter. Identifiers beginning with upper case letters are types, constructors or classes. Had a typo in my comment, sorry.

Comment: `main` is not a function, and not making this clear doesn't help, IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have a `main` function with type `Bool`, it always needs to be in the `IO` monad. What you probably want is something like *printing out* this boolean value. Then just do that!

```
main :: IO()
main = print $ is_instructor "foo"
```

Comment: So it would be `main :: IO Bool, main = return (is_instructor "foo")`.

Comment: @NiklasB. no! The main function can't directly return any values, it must use the `IO` monad to _interact_ with the environment.

Comment: I must've been sleeping while posting that comment. I meant `IO Bool` of course, but the function body itself wasn't valid Haskell as well :/ Of course that doesn't make a lot of sense, because it doesn't output anything, but it's a direct translation of OP's example :)

Answer (score 2):

You've certainly heard that Haskell is a purely functional language.  This means (among other things) that the only thing that a function can do in Haskell is compute a result that depends on the arguments; a function can't do I/O, or have a result that depends on something other than the arguments' values.

But Haskell allows you to write programs that do I/O and other effectful things.  How is this possible?  Well, what it means is that in Haskell, things that perform I/O or side effects are not functions; they are something else.  People often refer to them as **actions**.  I/O actions in Haskell have types of the form `IO a`.

The error you're getting here is that `main`, the entry point to a Haskell program, is required to be an action of type `IO ()`.  But `is_instructor` is a function of type `String -> Bool`, and `is_instructor "foo"` is a `Bool`.

Haskell doesn't allow you mix and match pure functions and actions haphazardly like that.  Applying a function and executing an action are two different things, and will require different code.